# Qual a melhor forma de adicionar um método estático à uma classe já existente no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, extensão, métodos-estáticos, newtonsoft

Estou criando uma aplicação *restfull* que utiliza a biblioteca [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) para enviar informações através dos *controllers*. Na minha aplicação, eu tenho inúmeras classes como por exemplo a de usuário:

```
public class UsuarioModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Visivel { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CriadoEm { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AtualizadoEm { get; set; }
}
```

Para que não seja enviadas propriedades `null` ou `default` eu quero sobrescrever o método estático propriedade dentro da classe `JObject.FromObject` assim:

```
public class JObject
{
    public static JObject FromObject(object o)
    {
        return FromObject(o, new JsonSerializer()
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
        });
    }
}
```

A intenção de fazer isso é que eu possa escrever menos código e padronizar toda a aplicação para sempre use essa configuração ao chamar o método.

O problema é que (até onde eu conheço) não tem como fazer um `override` de um método estático dentro de uma *extension class*.

O que devo fazer para implementar esse método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha solução foi criar o método que quis como uma extensão da classe e com outro nome, assim:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static JObject FromObjectCompressed(this JObject jObject, object o)
    {
        return JObject.FromObject(o, new JsonSerializer()
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
        });
    }
    public static JArray FromArrayCompressed(this JArray jObject, object o)
    {
        return JArray.FromObject(o, new JsonSerializer()
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem acesso à classe é só criar um método estático nela. Se quer fazer um `override` não quer um método estático, as duas coisas são inconsistentes. Um método estático existe globalmente, para a classe e portanto para a aplicação. Um método que permite ser sobrescrito é `virtual`, portanto adota polimorfismo dinâmico. Só tem sentido usar este tipo de mecanismo em instâncias de uma classe, portanto no objeto.

Se não tem acesso é só criar outra classe com o método que deseja e chamar este método da sua classe em vez de chamar a classe original. Se não consegue fazer isto precisa de outra solução, não é criando um método estático novo que vai conseguir. Sem um contexto maior não tem muito como ajudar.

A pergunta não deixa claro porque iria querer isto, mas parece que não é necessário e nada errado ocorre aí.

No futuro parece que poderá ter extensão de método estático em classes, mas mesmo que tenha, não é algo para ser abusado e muito menos permitirá `override` porque continuará não fazendo sentido.

Aliás, este componente de JSON será considerado obsoleto na próxima versão do .NET Core. Quase todas as vezes que usa `object` um panda morre na China :(

Comment: Entendo o que diz, a questão em si é a curiosidade que eu tinha se em C# era possível fazer algo do tipo ou de melhor forma.